# How to disable CURLOPT_ENCODING after it has been enabled?

Tags: php, curl

Take a cURL handle:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");

// Add request headers to curl_getinfo()
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); 

// Enable compression (usually gzip)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');

curl_exec($ch);
```

Now I would like to reuse this cURL handle to make another request. (I think that is common and recommended.)

But I want this second request to be made *without* an `Accept-Encoding` header. How can I undo the effect of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '')`?

I tried setting it to `null` and `false` but they had no effect.

Comment: When `CURLOPT_ENCODING` is blank it decodes the content using the method by which its encoded hence in most of the case it won't affect  until you want encoded contents. So if you include in that specific request in which you want to remove does it create any problem???

Comment: For starters it adds compression overhead.